# Android Studio/Gradle not finding AppCompat resources for tests

Tags: android, gradle, android-appcompat

I'm having a problem building tests in Android Studio using gradle. As far as I can tell it doesn't seem to include the resources for AppCompat v7 in its test compilation, which means my custom styles are referencing a whole bunch of AppCompat styles that it can't 'see'. This causes the wad of errors below.

It works totally fine for a regular non-test build, the styles are applied correctly and the project builds/installs/executes just fine with no errors. How can I resolve this error?

Full gradle error:

```
Execution failed for task ':processDebugTestResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /home/me/Android Studio/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4/aapt package -f --no-crunch -I /home/me/Android Studio/sdk/platforms/android-19/android.jar -M /home/me/Development/Android/MyApp/build/manifests/test/debug/AndroidManifest.xml -S /home/me/Development/Android/MyApp/build/res/all/test/debug -A /home/me/Development/Android/MyApp/build/assets/test/debug -m -J /home/me/Development/Android/MyApp/build/source/r/test/debug -F /home/me/Development/Android/MyApp/build/libs/MyApp-debug-test.ap_ --debug-mode
  Error Code:
    1
  Output:
    /home/me/Development/Android/MyApp/build/res/all/test/debug/values/values.xml:113: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar'.
    /home/me/Development/Android/MyApp/build/res/all/test/debug/values/values.xml:116: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'titleTextStyle'.
    /home/me/Development/Android/MyApp/build/res/all/test/debug/values-v11/values.xml:11: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar'.
    /home/me/Development/Android/MyApp/build/res/all/test/debug/values-v14/values.xml:11: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar'.
    /home/me/Development/Android/MyApp/build/res/all/test/debug/values/values.xml:119: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton'.
    /home/me/Development/Android/MyApp/build/res/all/test/debug/values-v11/values.xml:17: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton'.
    /home/me/Development/Android/MyApp/build/res/all/test/debug/values-v14/values.xml:17: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton'.
    /home/me/Development/Android/MyApp/build/res/all/test/debug/values/values.xml:123: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView'.
    /home/me/Development/Android/MyApp/build/res/all/test/debug/values/values.xml:127: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'dividerPadding'.
    /home/me/Development/Android/MyApp/build/res/all/test/debug/values/values.xml:126: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'showDividers'.
    /home/me/Development/Android/MyApp/build/res/all/test/debug/values-v11/values.xml:21: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView'.
    /home/me/Development/Android/MyApp/build/res/all/test/debug/values-v14/values.xml:21: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView'.
    /home/me/Development/Android/MyApp/build/res/all/test/debug/values/values.xml:131: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
    /home/me/Development/Android/MyApp/build/res/all/test/debug/values-v11/values.xml:29: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
    /home/me/Development/Android/MyApp/build/res/all/test/debug/values-v14/values.xml:29: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
    /home/me/Development/Android/MyApp/build/res/all/test/debug/values/values.xml:136: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat'.
    /home/me/Development/Android/MyApp/build/res/all/test/debug/values/values.xml:139: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionBarStyle'.
    /home/me/Development/Android/MyApp/build/res/all/test/debug/values/values.xml:141: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionBarTabBarStyle'.
    /home/me/Development/Android/MyApp/build/res/all/test/debug/values/values.xml:140: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionModeBackground'.
    /home/me/Development/Android/MyApp/build/res/all/test/debug/values-v11/values.xml:34: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat'.
    /home/me/Development/Android/MyApp/build/res/all/test/debug/values-v14/values.xml:34: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat'.
```

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.0+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0+'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+"
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
        instrumentTest {

            java.srcDirs = ['tests']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

values/styles.xml:

```xml
<resources>

    <style name="CPTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/cp_text</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/cp_background_light</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/CPThemeActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionModeBackground">@color/cp_titlebar_background</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/CPThemeTabBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CPThemeActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/cp_titlebar_background</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/cp_text</item>
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/CPThemeTitleTextStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CPThemeTitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/cp_text</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/cp_titlebar_background</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CPThemeTabBar"
        parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView" >
        <item name="android:background">@color/cp_background_light</item>
        <item name="android:divider">?android:attr/actionBarDivider</item>
        <item name="showDividers">middle</item>
        <item name="dividerPadding">12dp</item>
        <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CPThemeActionBarButton" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton">
        <item name="android:background">@color/cp_titlebar_background</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

values/styles-v11.xml and values/styles-v14.xml (they're copy-pastes of each other):

```xml
<resources>

    <style name="CPTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/cp_text</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/cp_background_light</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CPThemeActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@color/cp_titlebar_background</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/CPThemeTabBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CPThemeActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/cp_titlebar_background</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/cp_text</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/CPThemeTitleTextStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CPThemeTitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/cp_text</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/cp_titlebar_background</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CPThemeTabBar"
        parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView" >
        <item name="android:background">@color/cp_background_light</item>
        <item name="android:divider">?android:attr/actionBarDivider</item>
        <item name="android:showDividers">middle</item>
        <item name="android:dividerPadding">12dp</item>
        <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CPThemeActionBarButton" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton">
        <item name="android:background">@color/cp_titlebar_background</item>
    </style>

    <style name="BorderlessButton">
        <item name="android:background">@color/cp_background_light</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ListViewCells">
        <item name="android:background">@color/cp_background_dark</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/cp_text</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: try this in your build script:(use 19 instead of 18)   
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0+'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.+'

Comment: @descent Do you still need help with this question?

Comment: You should use more recent versions of all build tools available
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure that you've downloaded the latest extras (Android Support Library) via SDK-manager
2. Android 5.0 SDK via SDK-manager
3. Open the build.gradle file of your app-module and change your compileSdkVersion to 21